# CORS блокирует запросы на субдомен

Tags: ajax, cors, cross-domain

Пытаюсь с основного сайта сделать ajax запрос на поддомен для получения данных. В ответ получаю от мозиллы вот такое сообщение.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://core.piratron.net/registration.php.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match
>   ‘https://core.piratron.net’).

Хотя сам скрипт выполняется и данные в базу вносит. А ответ мозилой не передается в скрипт для дальнейшей обработки. Очень странное поведение браузера.

Сервер возвращает на основном домене заголовок

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Dec 2019 17:22:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2g
Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Dec 2019 17:22:18 GMT
ETag: "20c2-598e40dff2bdd-gzip"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://core.piratron.net
Content-Length: 2176
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

Я чего то недопонял в этих перекрестных запросах или как настроить чтоб все работло.

Comment: В Access-Control-Allow-Origin должен быть домен основного сайта с которого сделан запрос

Answer (score 0):

Это связанно с политикой браузера. Дабы вредоносные сайты не передавали ваши данные, куда не нужно. Чтобы ваши ajax запросы заработали между поддоменами, вам нужно разрешить cors политики между ними, что то вроде этого:

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'url вашего домена';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      ...
    }
}
```

Так будет выглядеть настройка для nginx. Так же вы можете найти конфигурации для CORS политик в гугле.

Comment: Так дело и в том, что данные отсылаются, скрипт обрабатывает их и добавляет в базу. А браузер не читает ответ. Вот это мне и странно.

Comment: прочитайте ответы запросов с обеих сторон, если обратно информация не возвращается, значит дело в корс политиках. Если возвращается, значит в вашем скрипте. Не обвиняйте браузер почем зря.

Comment: Поддерживаю автора вопроса. Не знаю почему, но недавно видел у себя в скрипте такое же поведение, при чем я разрешил cors. Когда я начал разбираться в проблеме, выяснил что отдает cors если в скрипте какая то синтаксическая ошибка, тогда вместо текста ошибки выдает корс…